# Mocking Data Object With Vitest For A Vue Component Using @tanstack/vue-query

Tags: vue.js, vitest, tanstack

I have a simple Vue component constructed around a hook. This component renders when there's data. I know that it is recommended to only test hooks if they are used in many components. I am confused how to properly mock that response within a wrapper. I've tried different passing the mocked object through `provide` and `data`, and tried to set it manually with `wrapper.setData`

```
<template>
    <el-card>
        <el-table v-if="monthSummaryData" :data="[monthSummaryData]" table-layout="auto" :loading="isFetching">
            <el-table-column v-for="column in columns" :key="column.prop" :prop="column.prop" :label="column.label">
                <template v-if="column.prop === 'memo'" #default="scope">
                    <el-statistic :title="column.label" :value="scope.row ? scope.row[column.prop] : ''"
                                  data-testid="memo-month-summary"/>
                </template>
                <template v-if="column.prop === 'monthlyAmountDebit'" #default="scope">
                    <el-statistic :title="column.label" :value="scope.row ? scope.row.monthly_amount_debit : ''"
                                  data-testid="monthly-amount-debit"/>
                </template>
            </el-table-column>
        </el-table>
    </el-card>

</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {computed, defineComponent, watch} from 'vue'
import {ElCard, ElStatistic, ElTable, ElTableColumn} from "element-plus";
import {useTransactionsStore} from "../../stores/transactionsStore";
import useMonthSummary from "../../api/hooks/transactions/useMonthSummary";

export default defineComponent({
    name: "MonthSummaryTable",
    components: {
        ElCard,
        ElStatistic,
        ElTable,
        ElTableColumn
    },
    setup() {

        const store = useTransactionsStore()

        const selectedMonth = computed(() => store.getSelectedMonth)

        const {data: monthSummaryData, isError, refetch, isFetching, isLoading, error} = useMonthSummary()

        const columns = [
            {prop: 'memo', label: 'Memo'},
            {prop: 'monthlyAmountDebit', label: 'Monthly Amount Debit'},
        ];

        watch(() => selectedMonth.value, (newValue: string) => {
            refetch();
        });

        return {monthSummaryData, isError, refetch, isFetching, isLoading, error, columns}
    }
})
</script>


<style scoped>
</style>
```

This is my wrapper:

```
        const wrapper = mount(MonthSummaryTable, {
            global: {
                components: {
                    ElTable,
                    ElStatistic,
                    ElTableColumn,
                    ElCard,
                },
                plugins: [VueQueryPlugin, createTestingPinia()],
            }
        });
```